# How do I show the user full name?

Tags: views, users

I am building a Drupal 7 site, and using the [Hybridauth module](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth). On my site, users can register with Facebook and Twitter (through the Hybridauth module), or regularly through the registration form.

When I am using a view, and add the field "User: Name", if the user registered through Hybridauth, it will show the full name; if the user registered on the site, and entered the full name in two dedicated fields, the view will show only the first name.

How can I present always the full name in both the cases?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the hybridauth module passes the username trough a hook before output an if the user is registered through hybridauth,
You should be able to get your desired outcome by also using the [Real name module](https://drupal.org/project/realname) which Hybridauth seems to integrate with.

Comment: Thanks. I have the real name module. My problem is that I need one field, that I will chose in views, that will present the full name, regardless the way the user registered to the site (hybridauth or core registration form). Do you think you can help me solve this issue?

Comment: Use username as a field in view.

Comment: Did that. When the user registered with hybridauth it present the full name (first name + last name). But, when the user registered with the core registration form, it present what ever he wrote on the user name field. I want it to present the first name + last name..

Comment: There should be a setting for this in the realname module. https://drupal.org/files/project-images/screenshot_0.png

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Real Name](https://drupal.org/project/realname) module and configure real name at admin/config/people/realname 
[image]

after that you have to configure HybridAuth at admin/config/people/hybridauth
[image]

And now Use username as field in view .